# find / replace on a file name using sed

Tags: bash, shell

I'm iterating over every file in a directory and attempting to find/replace the path part of the file with the following piece of code...

```
for f in /the/path/to/the/files/*
do
    file = $(echo $f | sec 's/\/the\/path\/to\/the\/files\///g`);
done
```

However, I get the following error with the assignment part of my code...

```
cannot open `=' (No such file or directory)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You must write `=` without spaces around it:

```
for f in /the/path/to/the/files/*
do
 file=$(echo $f | sec 's/\/the\/path\/to\/the\/files\///g');
done
```

Also, it would be better to use another symbol, not /, as a sed delimiter:

```
for f in /the/path/to/the/files/*
do
 file=$(echo $f | sec 's@/the/path/to/the/files/@@g')
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put spaces on either side of the equals sign:

```sh
for f in /the/path/to/the/files/*
do
    file=$(echo $f | sed 's/\/the\/path\/to\/the\/files\///g`);
done
```

Parameter expansion is a better way to accomplish this, however:

```sh
for f in /the/path/to/the/files/*
do
    file=${f#/the/path/to/the/files/}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for f in /the/path/to/the/files/*; do
    # no spaces around = sign
    file=$(echo $f | sed "s'/the/path/to/the/files/''g");
done
```